# How to load classes dynamically from jar file

Tags: java, class, jar, runtime, classloader

If i have a jar file that contain many class, how to get classes, and create instances at runtime. In this code i don't understand the Class.forName line, the MyClass is that class what contain the jar file or that class what will create after the jar file load?

```
URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader(
        new URL[] {myJar.toURI().toURL()},
        this.getClass().getClassLoader()
);
Class classToLoad = Class.forName("com.MyClass", true, child);
Method method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod("myMethod");
Object instance = classToLoad.newInstance();
Object result = method.invoke(instance);
```

Comment: Didyou forget `ClassLoader child=new URLClassLoader(` before your code?

Comment: See the documentation of [`Class#forName(String,boolean,ClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String,boolean,java.lang.ClassLoader)), [`Class#getConstructor(Class...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...)), and [`Constructor#newInstance(Object...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance(java.lang.Object...)).

Comment: Might also help to look at the documentation of [`ClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html).

Answer (score 0):

`Class.forName` loads a class.

The first parameter is the (canonical) name of the class. In this case, you try to load the class `com.MyClass`.

The second parameter specifies that the class should be initialized at that point(`static` variables are initialized and `static` blocks are run.

The third parameter is the `ClassLoader` the class will be loaded from. In your case, it will try to find the class from `myJar` but if the class isn't found there, it will try to load the class from the same `ClassLoader` the calling class has been loaded.